# Pointer to array type confusion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I thought that if I create a pointer to array type, I will be able to print all of its elements. I wrote a program like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{


    int arr[] = {4,2,3};
    //here arr is a (*arr)[3] type
    int (*p)[3], i;
    p = &arr;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
            printf("%d ", *(p)[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

output : 4 0 -673566907

My understanding is p will point to an array of 3 elements.
p+1 will point to another array of 3 elements.

```
arr=x   [ 1      2     3 ]
 y       [x]  [x+1] [x+2]

p=y(address of arr)
*p=x
**p = 1
*(*p+1) = 2
*(*p+2) = 3
```

I can print array like above. Does it mean p is actually double pointer?

P.S
Is it correct way to read

1. *(p)[1] should be read as "p is an array of 1 pointer to"
2. (*p)[1] should be read as "p is a pointer to an array of 1 element"
3. when we print

`printf("%d ", (*p)[1]); //here it should be read as p is a pointer to the` second element"

Answer (score 2):

You're dereferencing your pointer `p` in the `printf` statement incorrectly. Your code is acting as if `p` is an array of pointers to int instead of a pointer to an array of int. Instead of

```
printf("%d ", *(p)[i])
```

you want

```
printf("%d ", (*p)[i])
```

because you have to first turn `p` into the int[3] and then index into it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Line

```
printf("%d ", *(p)[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%d ", (*p)[i]);
```

It will access the *pointer-to-array* first, due to referencing `(*p)`, and then iterate through the content of the array with the `[]`-operator.

Consider the second iteration in the for-loop from your code which equals to:

```
printf("%d ", *(p + 1));
```

Trying to access the memory location `p+1` with the `*` leads to *undefined behavior* as others have already pointed out.

Comment: `My understanding is p will point to an array of 3 elements. p+1 will point to another array of 3 elements.`...so it does not quite match your statement here.

Comment: @acidlategamer yes. the parenthese is redundant in this case

Comment: While printing if I am using (*p)[1], then I am pointing to address of the second element or value, or getting only the address of the second value?

Comment: The expression `(*p)` gives you the memory address where the array `arr` is located. You then apply the `[ ]`operator to it. Thus, `(*p)[1]` is equal to `arr[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I will post my understanding from this thread,

**pointer to array type**

```
int arr[4] = {2,4,1,7};
int (*p)[4];//here p is a pointer, pointing to an array of 4 elements
p = &arr;
```

now if i want to access elements of 0th array

```
*p = *(p+0); //first element address pointed by p

*p+1 = *(p+0)+1;//second element addres pointed by p
```

and so on

now

```
**p = *(*(p+0)) ;//dreference of the 0th element of 0th array. equals to (*p)[0] expression.

*(*p+1) = *((*p+0)+1);//dereference of the 1st element of 0th array. equals to (*p)[1] expression

*(p)[1] = *(p+0)[1] =*(p+(1))= *(p+1) = next array.
```

Answer (score 0):

No, for any value other than 0 for `i`

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        printf("%d ", *(p)[i]);
```

causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you try to access invalid memory.

Therefore, the is no scope of `p` being a *pointer-to-pointer*, it is a pointer-to-array, and as they say, arrays are not pointers and vice-versa.

You can, however, take a pointer to the starting of the array and then loop over till you have valid elements in the array, that will be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your code well, but I edited it in this way and it worked. hope it can help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {4, 2, 3};
    int *p[3];
    int i = 0;
    p[0] = arr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
        printf("%d\n",*(p[0] + i) );

    return 0;
}
```